# Problems with Hyperref, Endfloat, Longtable and Appendix

Tags: tables, hyperref, longtable, floatrow

I am struggling with my table references in combination with endfloat and longtable. Somehow, they are not referring to the right table.

I get the following problem reported (I think that this is the problem):

> destination with the same identifier (name{table.2}) has been already
>   used, duplicate ignored \relax l.127 \end{longtable}
>   \end{spacing}\end{landscape}

I have seen people reporting the same error but never in combination with the packages I am using.

This is the code I am running:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e,array,longtable, afterpage}
\usepackage{lscape,booktabs}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=blue,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=green, filecolor=green, plainpages=false]{hyperref}  
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace} % double spacing
\usepackage[nolists,tablesfirst]{endfloat} % place figures at the end 

\newenvironment{ltable}
  {\footnotesize\begin{landscape}\begin{spacing}{1}\begin{longtable}}
  {\end{longtable}\end{spacing}\end{landscape}}
\DeclareDelayedFloatFlavor*{ltable}{table}


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
THIS IS THE TITLE PAGE

\end{titlepage}
\makeatother
\newpage 
\hypersetup{pageanchor=true} % removes "destination with the same identifier (name{page.1})"


%\listoftodos

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[h!tb]\centering \caption{Table 1}\label{Tab: 1}
    \footnotesize
    \begin{spacing}{1}
        \begin{tabular}{l r r r}\toprule
            Variable  & Mean & S.D. & N \\
        \end{tabular}
    \end{spacing}
\end{table}


\begin{ltable}[l]
    {
        >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{3.3cm} >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{3.3cm} >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{3.3cm} >{\RaggedRight}p{3.3cm} >{\RaggedRight}p{3.3cm} >{\RaggedRight}p{3.3cm}  >{\RaggedRight}p{3.3cm}}
    \caption{Table 2}\label{Tab: 2} \\ \toprule
    &(1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6)\\    

\end{ltable}


Table~\ref{Tab: 1}

Table~\ref{Tab: 2}. 

Table~\ref{Tab: A1}. 

Table~\ref{Tab: A2}. 

\clearpage


% % %APPENDIX % % % % % % % % % % % % %
\processdelayedfloats
\makeatletter
\efloat@restorefloats
\makeatother
\appendix


\renewcommand{\thefigure}{A\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand{\thepostfigure}{A\arabic{postfigure}}
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\setcounter{postfigure}{0}

\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand{\theposttable}{A\arabic{posttable}}
\setcounter{table}{0}
\setcounter{posttable}{0}

\footnotesize\begin{landscape}\begin{spacing}{1}\begin{longtable}{ 
                >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{3.3cm} >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{3.3cm} >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{3.3cm} >{\RaggedRight}p{3.3cm} >{\RaggedRight}p{3.3cm} >{\RaggedRight}p{3.3cm}  >{\RaggedRight}p{3.3cm}}
            \caption{Table A1}\label{Tab: A1} \\ \toprule
            &(1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6)\\    
        \end{longtable}\end{spacing}\end{landscape}

\newpage            

\footnotesize\begin{landscape}\begin{spacing}{1}\begin{longtable}{ 
                >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{3.3cm} >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{3.3cm} >{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}p{3.3cm} >{\RaggedRight}p{3.3cm} >{\RaggedRight}p{3.3cm} >{\RaggedRight}p{3.3cm}  >{\RaggedRight}p{3.3cm}}
            \caption{Table A2}\label{Tab: A2} \\ \toprule
                &(1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6)\\    
            \end{longtable}\end{spacing}\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

I hope this code is suitable to follow up on my problem. I appreciate any help.

Thank you!

Comment: Why is my code not working as a minimal example? I thought that I have created one :)

Comment: I have simplified my example. I hope this works better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `hyperref` needs unique anchor names. Since counters sometimes do not have unique names, it introduces a companion "counter" form as `\theH<counter>`. Then `\the<counter>` do not be to be unique, but `\theH<counter>` must.

The example redefines `\thetable`, but `\theHtable` is not changed. After making `\theHtable` unique again, the error is gone:

```
\renewcommand{\thetable}{A\arabic{table}}
\renewcommand*{\theHtable}{A\arabic{table}}
```